# Qual a diferença entre Flex e FlexBox no CSS?

Tags: css, css3

É comum ver as pessoas falando tanto flex quanto flexbox e, no meu entendimento, ambas se referem a mesma propriedade "display: flex" do css. Ainda assim, pesquisando mais um pouco encontrei coisas como "flexbox é um framework css" e outras informações meio contraditórias. Eu gostaria de saber se realmente existe alguma diferença real ou são apenas formas diferentes de se referir a mesma coisa.

Comment: Os dois termos se referem a mesma coisa (_Flex_, _Flexbox_, _Flexible Box Module_, _One-dimensional layout_ e etc). O flexbox não é um framework CSS e sim, um conjunto de funcionalidades e conceitos que já são intrínsecos na própria linguagem CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox é conceito do CSS3, assim como o CSS Grid.
Flex é a propriedade no código, como:
display: flex
ou
flex: 1..

mas sim, é comum usar as duas palavras pra se referenciar a mesma coisa..

Answer (score -2):

Cara vou te passar a minha visão, flex é o valor da propriedade display para as demais propriedades do FlexBox poder funcionar..... Se colocar o valor grid no lugar de flex não vai funcionar o flexbox e sim o CSS GRID.